# Como ver a porcentagem de uso de cpu de cada thread de um processo java

Tags: java, thread, multithreading, cpu

Bom, eu to com um problema de uso de cpu, e não sei exatamente qual classe ou Thread que está a consumir ( não tem como saber externamente do código ), queria saber se tem algum método que mostre todas as threads ativas com seu respectivo uso de CPU.
Tentei usar um codigo para ver as threads ativas, mas não to conseguindo ver a % da CPU, tem como fazer isso?

```
      ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();

            for(Long threadID : threadMXBean.getAllThreadIds()) {
                ThreadInfo info = threadMXBean.getThreadInfo(threadID);
                System.out.println("Nome da thread: " + info.getThreadName());
                System.out.println("Estado da thread: " + info.getThreadState());
                long cpusage = threadMXBean.getThreadCpuTime(threadID);
                System.out.println(String.format("Tempo usando a cpu: %.2f s",cpusage==0?0d:cpusage/100000000d));
            }
```

estou rodando o programa em docker na AWS, não tenho acesso ao terminal, preciso saber das informações por meio do código, ( ou algum outro meio de ver essas informações )

Comment: É no UNIX/Linux? Não vou lembrar agora mas tem como ver a informação das threads com comandos como `top -H`. Dê uma pesquisada.

Comment: dentro da pasta do jdk tem o JConsole também, dá pra ter uma visão geral

Comment: não tenho acesso ao console externo, precisava dessa informação dentro do código

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar isso executar comandos Linux. Provavelmente conseguirá obter a informação com algum comando linux

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -aF");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println("line: " + s);
p.waitFor();
System.out.println ("exit: " + p.exitValue());
p.destroy();
```

Veja aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403226/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-java